# Tier Dimension based on measure value

Tags: sql-server, ssas, pivot, mdx

I have a case where i need to have a dimension based on measure value.
example :

[image]

[image]

the fact table is linked to date dimension through DateID,
and what i want to add is another dimension for Tier, but the problem is that there's no specific range for date selection and it can be whatever the user select on the date dimension.

I can't do it in data warehouse as the date range to calculate and group the amount into each tier is not predefined. So is it possible to create something like this?

[image]

the only way i can achieve close to this is using analysis cube but it'll only come out as row
example :
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I can't do it in data warehouse as the date range to calculate and group the amount into each tier is not predefined.` > How is it calculated?